# Can single quotes be preserved when passing a variable to a command on stdin?

Tags: bash, stdin, single-quotes

Example:

```
 $ foo="text with 'single quotes'"
 $ echo $foo
```

gives me

```
 text with 'single quotes'
```

which is the output I'm after, but I would like to pass `$foo` on stdin with the same result. Something like one of the following:

```
 $ xargs echo <<< $foo

 $ echo $foo | xargs echo
```

Both of these give me

```
 text with single quotes
```

**Is there a way to keep the single quotes without control over the contents of foo?**

I'm looking for a solution that works regardless of the command, I chose `xargs echo` because I think it shows the behavior simply. The solution may not exist but if anyone has any tips that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doubling up on the parsing, so you need to double up on the quoting.

```
$: foo="text with \'single quotes\'"
$: xargs echo <<< "$foo"
text with 'single quotes'
```

so by the same token,

```
$: foo="text with 'single quotes'"
$: xargs echo <<< \"$foo\"
text with 'single quotes'
```

This is dependent on the number of parsing passes, though, which is what you need to understand and accomodate. Applying a two-layer solution to a command with only one layer of parsing has the opposite effect -

```
$: echo \"$foo\"
"text with 'single quotes'"
```

Now the extra quotes become visible.

Comment: I chose this one as `xargs echo` was a drop in for another command I was running and so this one matches best. I've updated my question to make that more clear!

Comment: ha, and even though the second code block answers this question, turns out the solution to my specific problem that prompted this more general question was to `sed` in some \ before each `'` into the equivalent of `$foo`.

Answer (score 6):

By default xargs will parse quotes and backslashes. Use `-d` to set an explicit item delimiter and disable this behavior, which is rarely ever desirable.

```
$ xargs -d '\n' echo <<< "$foo"
text with 'single quotes'
```

Comment: I've updated my question as I realized it was xargs specific as I originally wrote it and I didn't intend it that way. Regardless, this helped me understand that it was the command that was applying additional parsing and not something inherent in `<<<` (here-string) or `|` (pipe). Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

If you want xargs to ignore quotes, try using xargs flag xargs -0 like this:

```
foo="text with 'single quotes'"

echo $foo | xargs -0 echo
text with 'single quotes'

xargs -0 echo <<< $foo
text with 'single quotes'
```